# Fun teaching techniques for children meditation class

Tags: meditation-practicalities, parents, learning-materials, learning

Can someone help ?  i am looking for fun teaching of meditation and Buddhist teaching from age 4 ~ 13 old.

Also help with morality, environmental protection, chanting, Buddhist religion's etiquette and meditation would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Buddhism SE. You might find these question interesting - [Buddhist themed crafts and activities](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10243/157) also [Teaching buddhist concepts to a child](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9006/teaching-buddhist-concepts-to-a-child) and [How do you tell a 4 year old who the Buddha was](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7268/157). Good luck with your meditation teaching

Answer (score 2):

Here's a video series on how to meditate for children:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB4C918E1E338A6F1

DVDs are also available.

Answer (score 1):

There are some guided meditations for children on BuddhaNet: [*"Teaching Meditation in the Classroom"*](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/meditate/guide.htm).